# What is the probability of hitting the line?

Tags: probability

We have a line drawn in the floor, say 100 cm. This line color was blue. Another man came and drew a short line randomly on our line and in red, say the length of that line is 5 cm.

[image]
We have a piece of metal that falls randomly on that line. It is clear that this piece probability to fall on the red line is 5%

> My question
>
> What if we have $2$ pieces? What is the probability of at least one of them hit the red line ? And how it get calculated?
>
> What if we have $3$ or $N$ pieces then what is the probability at least one of them hit the line?

My attempt was like following:

$$p(x) = 0.05$$

the probability of double event is $0.05 \cdot 0.05$ which is $0.0025$ which is wrong for sure. The probability has to increase not decrease.

Thanks

Comment: Try to calculate first that you won't hit once in N attempts.

Comment: look up [binomial experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). In your case $n$ is the number of pieces, $p=0.05$ is the probability of success and you need to find $\mathbb P(X\ge 1)=1-\mathbb P(X=0)$.

Comment: @farruhota thanks, this equation is what i need  P(X≥1)=1−P(X=0).